# what is the difference between one node connected to other after three nodes and 2nd degree?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

i am running the queries to find if node `a` is connected to node `b` directly or indirectly. for directly i can use

`MATCH (n)-[r]->(a)` OR `MATCH (n)-[r]->(b)`

when i use the query

`MATCH (b)-[r*1..2]->(a)`

the results are different. i am confused to understand what is the difference between below mentioned two queries.

1- `OPTIONAL MATCH L=a-->c-->e-->b with a,b,L,p,q,n`

2- `OPTIONAL MATCH M=(a)-[r*1..2]->(b)`

Are these both queries are the same. if they are then the results for both in my case are different. 
what i wanted to see, `a` is connected to `b` after two hop distance. 
i will be very grateful for your contribution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
MATCH (b)-[r*1..2]->(a)
```

Means match one or two hops away.  So the result is different from your first queries, because your first queries match exactly one hop away.  This one goes further, so the results are different.  Here, "hops" mean relationships not nodes.

This query:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH L=a-->c-->e-->b with a,b,L,p,q,n
```

Is very different because you're navigating through 2 intermediate nodes (c and e) with **3** intermediate relationships (a->c, c->e, e->b).

By the way, you can of course use optional match here, but for you it's not needed.  If a and b must be connected, then using optional match doesn't really change anything for you here.

**So you need to decide whether you want something 2 hops/relationships away, or if you want something 2 hops/nodes away, that's different.**

Another way of writing 2 hops/relationships away would be this:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[r1]-(m)-[r2]-(b)
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thanks Frobber, so it means generally two hops away OR one intermediate node away is the same thing. right?

Comment: A "hop" is a relationship (for me) so I interpret "two hops away" to mean "2 relationships away" which is the same thing as one intermediate node.